# Mobile App - Best approach to display 20000 data items

Tags: design-patterns, mobile

I made an application to scan malware and dangerous files on Android devices. In worse case, there may be over 1000 infected items (even more) to show. I don't ask about correctness of scanning engine, I want to find some ideas how should I display scanning result to users. I mean, assume I find 1000 or 20.000 infected items, which is the good approach to display them to users. A flat list of 20k items is not readable, I think.
This question may not have 100% exactly answer, but I hope we can find some good ideas/experience to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to display them for the user so he/she can click on one and see more details about it? Or are you looking to display a sum of everything and summarize what you've found?

Comment: I want to display them sothat users can do some actions with them (such as:view details, clean, delete,...)

Comment: I would suggest showing it as a list and using lazy loading. I would also consider having colors for different severity levels...

Comment: Thanks, but with thousand of items it isn't good idea.

Comment: What is the approach you're gonna go with?

Comment: Im still dont have any good idea. Just think about clarify them by type or by first letter in name, but the list may so long

Comment: That's a good idea. Or you can display a pie chart and then when they click on it you can let them choose between different types and so on...